# Access to Windows RDP only via VPN

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, openvpn

I'm a beginner, I installed OpenVPN for the first time on Windows Server 2019 and on a private computer with Windows 10. The VPN configuration was correct because the connection to the server is what I see in the OpenVPN logs on the server. In Firewall settings I changed that port 3389 would be open to the local network. After this change, I am connecting to the server by the old method (using public IP server: 60.50.40.30:3389) and I get a connection error and this is good. However, when I try to connect by local address, I cannot connect via RDP to the server.

Windows 10 - local network

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.157(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
```

Windows 10 - OpenVPN

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.6(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.5
```

Windows Server 2019 - local network

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 60.50.40.30(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.248.0
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 60.50.1.1
DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 80.60.40.20
```

Windows Server 2019 - TAP-Windows Adapter

```
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.1(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.8.0.2
```

What else should I do or check?